# SELECT en SQL Server de la ultima semana

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola Quisiera hacer un SELECT de SQL server pero que solo me selecione los ultimos dias transcurridos de Lunes a Domindo NO los ultimos 7 dias seria algo como este:

```
select GETDATE() - 7
```

pero en ese solo me sale los ultimos 7 Dias pero quiero es que empieze desde el dia Lunes y termine los dias Domingo

¿Como hago para que ese select me muestre, si estoy en el dia martes, solo DOMINGO y LUNES sin contar el Dia Martes hasta que este termine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `WEEKDAY` para obtener el día relativo a la semana (de 1 a 7). Esta numeración varía por región, por lo que debemos estandarizarla primero usando `SET DATEFIRST`. Lo que hacemos en el siguiente ejemplo es restarte este número a la fecha del parámetro, tal que calce Lunes o Domingo.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- 1 Lunes, 7 Domingo

DECLARE @Fecha DATE = GETDATE()

SELECT
  LunesPasadoMasCercano = DATEADD(
    DAY,
    1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Fecha),
    @Fecha),
  DomingoSiguiente = DATEADD(
    DAY,
    7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Fecha),
    @Fecha)
```

Ten en cuenta que si vas a hacer un filtro de rango, te conviene hacerlo entre Lunes (inclusive) y Lunes siguiente (sin incluir), por un tema de hora en las columnas `DATETIME`, y hacerlo contra fechas del tipo `DATE` o que tengan hora `00:00`.